# Pyproject using flat-layout creating several folders in lib folder instead one module

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, pyproject.toml

I was using a src layout before to create a module, but was requested to do it in flat-layout. I have reads all docs from setuptools but they are very confusing (I feel like they are unreadable and they lack of examples). The .toml for src layout was:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools", "setuptools-scm"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "detection_engine"
authors = [
    {name = "Josiah Carberry", email = "josiah_carberry@brown.edu"},
]
description = "Detection Engine"
readme = "README.md"
requires-python = ">=3.8"

dependencies = [
    "requests",
    'importlib-metadata; python_version<"3.10"',
]
dynamic = ["version"]



[project.optional-dependencies]
yolox = [
    "loguru==0.7.2",
    "tqdm==4.66.1",
    "thop==0.1.1.post2209072238",
    "ninja==1.11.1.1",
    "tabulate==0.9.0",
    "psutil==5.9.6",
    "tensorboard==2.14.0",
    "pycocotools>=2.0.7",
    "onnx>=1.13.0",
    "onnx-simplifier",
]
mmcv = [
    "loguru==0.5.3",
    "mmdet==2.28.1",
    "mmcv-full",
    "numpy",
    "opencv-python==4.7.0.72",
    "pydantic",
    "pytest-cov==4.0.0",
    "pytest==7.2.2",
    "torch==2.0.1",
    "torchvision==0.15.2"
]

[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["src"]
include = ["*"]
namespaces = true # set false to not include folders without __init__.py file.
```

but when I put where = ["."] it creates 4 folders in the lib folder instead of one module "detection_engine" package with 4 folders. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, any help is appreciated.

```
├── detection
├── detection_engine.egg-info
├── dist
├── engines
├── environment.yml
├── MANIFEST.in
├── mmcv_install.sh
├── models
├── pyproject.toml
├── README.md
├── requirements_mmcv.txt
├── requirements_yolox.txt
├── setup.py
└── tracking
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write:

```ini
[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["."]
include = ["*"]
namespaces = true
```

You are telling setuptools to scan for all folders in the root directory that looks like a Python package (even if they don't contain `__init__.py` or any `.py` file[^1]) and add all of them into the wheel archive in a way that they will be later installed in the `site-packages` directory of the users.

It seems that your project structure contains indeed 4 folders that probably could be understood as packages: `detection`, `engines`, `models`, `tracking`.

If you want to your users to write `import detection_engine`, I suggest creating a `detection_engine` folder, moving all the relevant folders and files that should be installed inside of it (note how the [example in the `setuptools` docs](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html#flat-layout) does employ a "parent" folder).

Alternatively if you want to ignore certain folders in the top-level, you can also change the `tool.setuptools.packages.find.include` config to `include = ["<name-of-your-top-level-package>*"]`

[^1]: Python allows you to import folders as namespace packages even if they don't contain `.py` files.